# How can I delete the contents of a folder from the command prompt in windows?

Tags: deployment, command-line, msbuild

I am writing a deployment script using MSBuild. I want to clean my web directories prior to copying all the new files in. My current "Clean" target looks like this:

```
 <Target Name="Clean">
    <Exec Command="del %(DeploymentSet.LocalWebRoot)\* /Q /F /S" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
  </Target>
```

This takes an considerable amount of time as each file is deleted from each subfolder individually.

Is there a nice way to remove everything from a given folder with out deleting that folder? I want to maintain my permissions and vdir setup info.

Comment: I would say to del *, but you're already doing that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `rmdir /s /q` each sub-directory individually, then `del %(DeploymentSet.LocalWebRoot)\* /Q /F` your clean target. For example:

```
 <Target Name="Clean">
    <Exec Command="rmdir %(DeploymentSet.LocalWebRoot)\subdir1 /Q /S" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
    <Exec Command="rmdir %(DeploymentSet.LocalWebRoot)\subdir2 /Q /S" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
    ...
    <Exec Command="rmdir %(DeploymentSet.LocalWebRoot)\subdirN /Q /S" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
    <Exec Command="del %(DeploymentSet.LocalWebRoot)\* /Q /F" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Trying to keep it generic so that clean can work for any given DeploymentSet.LocalWebRoot... will have to think about that one.

Comment: Yeah, there's a tradeoff there, and rmdir might not be significantly faster to warrant the trade.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify the names of each sub-directory, use this:

```
<Target Name="Clean">
    <Exec Command="del /F /Q %(DeploymentSet.LocalWebRoot)\*.*" />
    <Exec Command="for /d /r &quot;%(DeploymentSet.LocalWebRoot)&quot; %v IN (*) DO rd /S /Q &quot;%v&quot;" />
</Target>
```